# How do I install Ubuntu on a second hard drive?

Tags: system-installation

I am going to be buying a second hard drive for my desktop here pretty soon, because my current hard drive is a piece of junk running windows 7.

What I want to know is how to install Ubuntu on the second drive. I am looking for a non complicated answer as I am not familiar with the Ubuntu lingo. I am so sick of Windows.. I used Ubuntu before but it didn't work properly. When I installed it, it said I didn't have enough space... Even though I had 600GB to use.

Anyway if anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Linux distributions generally require very little space - at least much less than Windows Vista or 7.
A clean install occupies just several GBs and a partition of 20 to 30 GBs is usually enough for a desktop installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install ubuntu on a second hard drive with windows being on the first?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171759/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-second-hard-drive-with-windows-being-on-the-first)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is a classic installation of Ubuntu on your second HDD. If you do not know how to do, search it on Ask Ubuntu. There is obviously a link for that on this website. Otherwise, search it on the rest of the Internet.

After that, you have to ensure that the computer will boot on this install of Ubuntu. When you switch on your computer, it looks at the boot devices list (CD or DVD burner, Hard Drive Disks, floppy it you still get one...). On each boot device, it will look if there is something to boot on. The computer will use the first boot device where he finds something bootable and will boot on the bootable thing of the boot device. So what you have to do is placing your new HDD before your current one in the list in order to boot on Ubuntu instead of your old Windows 7 (otherwise it will boot on the Windows 7 of your current HDD because he is before your new HDD and its Ubuntu in the list). For this, you have to go into your computer's BIOS or UEFI (I do not know what you have) to modify the list of boot devices. If you do not know how to do, search it on Google.

Comment: Also, can't I use wubi to install on a different drive?

Comment: @Keith454: perhaps but I do not really trust Wubi. The "good old" classic method to install an OS has proved that it is a good method so I prefer using it instead of Wubi. It gives me some guarantees instead of Wubi. Wubi must work and you can use it if you want. But personally I prefer doing just like in the answer. However Wubi do not modify the booting list AFAIK.