# triple boot with second Ubuntu installation on second drive

Tags: 14.04, grub2

**Current Situation**: I already have a dual boot system with Windows & Ubuntu on first hard drive.

**Desired Situation**: Add a second installation of Ubuntu on a second drive (and pick desired OS on startup from GRUB menu).

I am assuming installing Ubuntu on the second drive will be no different than any other installation. Just want to know what special steps, if any, I need to do to ensure that GRUB will find this second Ubuntu install.

Comment: OK, it's feasible. What's the question?

Comment: Yes .. what holds you back from trying it ?

Comment: I'm concerning about mucking up GRUB, something else bootloader related, or my first install of Ubuntu.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system and installs? Either way best to partition in advance and only use Something Else install option, choose sdb as install drive for grub2's boot loader(only works if BIOS). And if BIOS then you will have different default grub on sda & sdb but can boot all installs from either one.  Do you currently have data on second drive? Is it gpt or MBR(msdos) partitioned? You can always unplug sda and then system only sees one drive to install into. But you have to run `sudo update-grub` on sda install to find new install on sdb once plugged back in.

Comment: Second drive is brand new and unpartitioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)