# W10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: dual-boot

My Acer notebook has 2 spaces for HDD.  The main one is occupied by a SSD loaded with W10 and the second is free.  Is it possible to use this free space for a HDD loaded with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and to use those two operating systems alternatively and separately ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

You could, if your PC BIOS permits it, but switching would require going into your BIOS Setup ( by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> or some other key, depending on your PC model which you have not told us ) every time to select the boot drive, unless your PC has a hardware button (e.g., the [Blue Button](http://www.laptopcloseout.com/media/pages/thinkpad-featutes-nofpr.jpg) on some Lenovos) to allow you to override the Boot Order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and I would recommend you to do this also. For the boot menu I choose Grub Menu of Linux to give me access to every possible boot option (The menu of Windows 10 is rather buggy to my opinion.