# Windows 10 on one drive, and Ubuntu on another

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows

I have a ssd, and two hard drives. I have windows on the ssd, and use the one hard drive on windows as well. I just picked up another hard drive and haven't even installed it into my system yet. My question is, can I dedicate the new drive for Ubuntu only? and still keep the other two windows only. If I can, how exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Often safest to disconnect Windows drive(s) and install to new drive as if it was the only drive. Be sure to install in same boot mode as Windows, either both as UEFI boot or both as BIOS boot. Otherwise you must use Something Else and best to partition in advance. And be sure to include an ESP on Ubuntu drive as it will be default use first drive for install of UEFI version of grub. But then you can copy those files to Ubuntu drive from first drive and reconfigure to make it bootable on its own. (easier to disconnect drive). You may not have to physically disconnect, just change UEFI setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can, I have only done it with 1 SSD and 1 HDD in the past, but it does work. Go ahead and boot Ubuntu from a USB, go through the install and make sure you click "Something Else" when picking a drive to install it on. Select the drive you want Ubuntu installed on, then for the grub boot loader, I recommend you install it on your main drive (The SSD or the other Hard drive, whichever one is primary/ First in the boot order). Grub will automatically detect the other windows installations on the other 2 drives and it will let you pick which one to boot from. If you don't want Ubuntu to be the default when it boots, you can modify the default option in "nano /etc/default/grub"
https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/