# What is the industry standard to installing ubuntu in a windows machine?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, external-hdd

I have before installed ubuntu alongside windows but I had to format that drive so both ubuntu and windows were gone so I wanna know if its recommendable and if its even possible to install ubuntu in a separate hard drive that will live inside my computer say disk f: and only install ubuntu there by itself nothing more while having disk c: for windows only.Will I have to always go to bios bootsetting to tell my pc I wanna boot from disk f or c? or I can use the dual install option and somewhere in the settings will tell me to install ubuntu in disk f: while still keeping the dual bootable screen that comes by default?(I have not attempted this for fear i will mess up and install ubuntu in c rather than f by itself) or should I just install in an external ssd running in wither usb c or 3.0 .Please tell me what is the most recommendable way to run ubuntu or how you run it to avoid having the issued I had.

Comment: I didn't understand all of your requirements, but I believe yes it can be done.  I'd suggest using the 'something else' option in the installer, as it lets you create/use any partitioning scheme you like (including no-format) giving you full control of how you install.  You then are asked where or if to install grub.  You didn't provide details of your release of windows, which Ubuntu release you mean, nor if you are using BIOS or UEFI - so my suggestion is vague as I don't know your full setup.  (you can use your bios/uefi to boot grub or not depending on options chosen)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Comment: Once you install Ubuntu on a second drive, set it as first HDD in BIOS, boot it and run "sudo update-grub", That should add the Windows on the other disk to grub menu. you can then decide default OS.

Comment: I installed ubuntu when I attempted my installation

Comment: @C.S.Cameron So should I unplug my windows HDD as suggested in the article by karel

Comment: @atds9511 : No, "sudo update-grub" should be run with the Windows disk plugged in. That is how grub updater knows it is there. (You can unplug the Windows disk during the Ubuntu install process though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Installing Ubuntu on Second Drive, Windows on First

- Unplug Windows hard drive.
- Install Ubuntu on second hard drive.
- Plug Windows drive back in.
- Boot Ubuntu hard drive.
- In Terminal run:

  sudo update-grub

This should automatically add a Windows menuentry to the grub boot menu.

You can change back to Windows bootloader, (first HDD), using BIOS if desired.