# Install Ubuntu on second SSD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I am currently using a Xiaomi Mi Air 13 laptop which has two slots for SSD drives. In the first one, which came with the computer, I have Windows 10. I have now bought a second SSD for the second slot, where I want to install Ubuntu. I am nos sure if this can be done and how will dual boot work if I do it. I could use some help in the instalation process.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/)

Comment: Yes it can be done. Ubuntu will detect windows and add it to the bootloader, meaning when you boot your machine you will have the option to boot both OS.

Comment: Main thing to remember is to know which ssd you want to install ubuntu to.  Many people have made a mistake and installed over windows.