# Dual-Boot Ubuntu 19.10 on Windows 10 where Linux is on a different harddrive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have Windows 10 installed on my SSD (C:) and I want to install Ubuntu on my HDD (D:). Does this change anything when trying to Dual-Boot Windows and Ubuntu? I found a lot of tutorials but they were always using the same drive for both Windows and Linux. Does this change something in the installation-process or is it the same? If you know a tutorial that covers these aspects, could you link it for me?

On my HDD are some games for Windows, documents, applications etc. so it's not empty. That's why I think its a bit different from the link which was suggested to be the same question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Comment: @karel I forgot to mention that I already have Documents/Files/Games for Windows on my second hard drive, where I want to install Ubuntu.

Comment: So, I'm not entirely sure if this is the same scenario.

Comment: There's a [screen for that](https://superuser.com/a/1517594) in the Ubuntu installer. The 1st screen to select the disk. The 2nd screen to allocate drive space by dragging the divider.

Comment: @karel Is this really safe? Or are there known bugs/issues that can lead to data-loss etc when using the build-in partitioning.

Comment: If Windows is installed in UEFI mode then Ubuntu must be installed in UEFI mode too. If Windows is installed in BIOS mode then Ubuntu must be installed in BIOS mode too. This is done by default by the Ubuntu installer. If one of the OSs is installed in BIOS mode and the other OS in UEFI mode then one of the OSs may not boot from the boot menu, but it still may be possible to boot it from BIOS.

Comment: Okay so Ubuntu will try to install itself in the same configuration needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103456/discussion-between-karel-and-doesbaddel).