# How can i install linux in a different hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Recently i am using windows 10.I want to use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongsinde it.There are two drives in my laptop.One ***ssd and a hdd***.My windows os is installed in the ssd.Now **i want to install linux in my hdd**.How can i do it?

Comment: We don't support generic GNU/Linux or Linux, you've not provided any OS that is on-topic for this site so please be specific, ie. OS & release details.  (I would use 'something-else', 'manual' or 'manual partitioning' depending on installer & release being used to do what you want, but how it appears differs on release & flavor being used of which you gave no specifics).

Comment: I wanna use Linux mint

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are welcome here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Mint forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

### Installing Ubuntu on Different Hard Drive than Windows

**The following assume that you are starting with a blank HDD** and that any data on it has been backed up as it will be overwritten.

- Download Ubuntu ISO, 18.04 LTS will stay supported until 2023, (or 2028 with free Extended Security Maintenance).
- Create an installer USB using Rufus or balenaEtcher.
- Boot installer under same mode Windows is installed in, BIOS or UEFI.
- Start Install Ubuntu.
- Select Language, click "Continue".
- Select Keyboard layout, click "Continue".
- Select Wireless network, click "Continue".
- Select installation preference and select "Download updates while installing Ubuntu", Select "Install third-party software ...", click "Continue".
- If asked about mounted partitions, select Yes, click "Continue".
- Do not use Advanced feature disk encryption for this install method.
- At "Installation type" select "Something else", click "Continue".
- Under Device for boot loader installation select the target HDD.
- Select "New Partition Table".
- Click Continue on the drop down.
- If Windows is UEFI, Click "free space" and then "+" Add a small efi partition.
- Click "free space" and then "+".
- Select "Primary", "New partition size ..." = as you require, "Beginning of this space", Ext4, and Mount point = "/" then OK.
- Click Install now.
- Confirm partitions to be formatted.
- Select your location. select "Continue".
- Insert your name, computer name, username, password and select if you want to log in automatically or require a password.
- Select "Continue".
- Wait until install is complete.
- Boot computer, confirm that Windows is listed in the grub boot menu and that it loads.

If not you may need to select between the Windows disk and the Ubuntu disk when booting.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS stays supported to 2028???  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop & server come with 5 years of standard support, which can be extended through ESM to provide longer. Flavors of Ubuntu come with 3 years, Ubuntu Core ...   Your statement on supported life is somewhat incorrect (most people will read that as meaning *standard support* which is only the first part of the full support picture) http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, have edited answer, Canonical provides Ubuntu Advantage Essential subscriptions, which include ESM, free of charge for individuals on up to 3 machines. For our community of Ubuntu members we will gladly increase that to 50 machines. Your personal subscription will also cover Livepatch, FIPS and CIS hardening tools.