# How to install Kubuntu on other hard disk

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, dmraid

I would like to install Kubuntu 12.10 on my computer. I have 2 hard drives, 500 GB each. I have Windows 7 Home Premium installed on one disk, and I want to install Kubuntu 12.10 on the other. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

See [How to install Ubuntu on a second hard drive with Windows being on the first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171759/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-second-hard-drive-with-windows-being-on-the-first).

In short:

1. First download the ISO file then burn it to a CD/DVD or use
   Unetbootin to get a bootable USB, select the Installation media to
   boot first from your BIOS.
2. Once you're in the Live Session, choose Install Kubuntu.
3. When you get to the Choose an Option screen, select **Do Something
   Else**.
4. Locate the Second drive and choose to Install the System on the
   second drive. You can [follow the instructions on how to make different partitions.](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/install_kubuntu_2.html#partitioning). However, this page tells you to use `ext3` as the type of partition. `ext4` is newer and is now the default. You can use `ext4` partition type for the `/` and `/home` partitions.
5. Choose to also install the bootloader on the 2nd drive, make sure
   it's the drive and not a partition (i.e. /dev/sda and not /dev/sda1)
6. In the BIOS set to **boot from the Ubuntu drive**. This may boot
   straight to Ubuntu at first. If that happens open a terminal and
   type `sudo update-grub`. From the next boot you should get the
   choice to boot Ubuntu or Windows. See [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives)

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer is right, please put the green check mark on the left. This will help others looking for the answer to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/install_kubuntu_2.html#partitioning
just select the hard drive that you want to install kubuntu to and proceed with the instructions in the link.