# How can I install Linux on my extra hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I have two 1TB hard drives in my computer:

- one for Windows 10 for my gaming
- one empty, which I want to install Linux on to use as my workstation.

I have no idea how to do the installation and all the tutorials I've seen only teach you how to set up a dual boot on one single hard drive by partitioning.

I would really like to avoid partitioning my hard drive with the Windows OS on it and keep the two separate.

Can someone enlighten me on how to do this please?

Comment: Did you check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive for instructions?  Any UEFI install instructions should work, but be aware of bug 1396379 (grub goes to first disk's EFI partition). See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182302 also.

Comment: Use a ubuntu USB stick that you have burned the ISO to.  Boot computer with USB and use 'try ubuntu' and check everything works.  Ubuntu should see both hard drives and label them as sda and the other sdb.  Make sure you know which one has Windows on it.  You can now go to 'install ubuntu' and use the option 'something else'.  Install ubuntu on the hard drive that does not have Windows on it.  DO NOT make Mistake with which hard drive.

Comment: Partition in  advance using gpt and only use Something Else install option to choose which partition is which. Generally better to have smaller / (root) and larger /home or data partition(s). Swap partition now not required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Be sure to include ESP - efi system partition. If not disconnecting drive, see work around: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) and [How to install ubuntu on a second hard drive with windows being on the first?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171759/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install Linux with an installation media (with USB,etc) and installing the OS on the hard disk that you want, make sure that nothing important is on that hard disk.