# Booting my laptop with Ubuntu live USB (try) but not with an USB Installed Ubuntu ¿?

Tags: boot, usb

First of all to notice that my question is about why Installed Ubuntu in a usb key does'nt boot and Try Ubuntu Live does. And why it boots in one laptop and not in another. I didn't found any similar question, so this one is not duplicated question....

I've created a bootable USB key drive (1), from an Ubuntu 18 installed in my desktop computer, using the "Startup Disk Creator" tool

With this USB Key I'm able to boot my laptop (HP Probook 430 G5), and I get a grub menu and I can select Try Ubuntu without install or Install ubuntu, etc. It runs OK.

But I'm not able to boot the same laptop with another USB Key (2) with Ubuntu Installed from the first USB Key (1) using the Install Ubuntu menu option, or booting firts USB Key (1) with Try Ubuntu and then running "Install ubuntu"...
It gets me into Bios setup again and again without booting (selecting to boot with USB Key (2) and USB Key (1) removed.

I've checked that this second USB Key (2) in another laptop (HP Probook 430 G2) and IT BOOTS OK ¿? what's wrong?
I've tried also to use different USB Keys (i've tried 3 different for both (1 and 2).

Why the 'try ubuntu' usb key (1) boots OK and the installed ubuntu one (2) does not?
Anyone here is able to help me?

Comment: Is not an installation issue (like the question your are reporting as duplicate). It's a booting issue... Thanks.

Comment: The booting issue is probably because there is no EFI System Partition (ESP) created in the USB Key 2, during installation. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079) for how to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks user68186 because that was the reason... the EFI partition... I've did the installation mannualy (something else) and selected the usb key (2) and first created a 500Mb EFI partition then a ext4 mounted on / and then a swap partition... 

BUT when booting I've to press esc/sup button for Boot Menu and I choose USB key (2) for boot,,, and it says something unreadable on screen (sooo fast) and it boots again, I'v to press ESc/Sup button for boot menu and then I'm able to choose EUFI Ubuntu usb key (2) ... then it finnaly boots!

Answer (score 1):

## Problem: No ESP in the USB key 2

The booting issue is probably because there is no EFI System Partition (ESP) created in the USB Key 2, during installation. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079) for how to solve this problem

Also see [Installing Ubuntu without touching Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037843/installing-ubuntu-without-touching-windows)

Also see the **Option 2: Two Drives Two ESPs** section of this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171759/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-second-hard-drive-with-windows-being-on-the-first/1165237#1165237) for details about using the Something Else and creating ESP partition manually.

Hope this helps