# Dualboot on separate drives going straight to win10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, 19.04

Hi all I'm a bit green on this, have searched previous Q/A and tried multiple suggestions to no avail so far. I usually get around fairly well but this whole boot-ordeal is an unexplored wormhole for me so bare with me and thanks for any suggestions. Feel free to ask for clarification/elaboration or logs (if you can suggest how to generate them)

Objective:
Dualboot Ubuntu19/Win10, Separate drives.

Background:

1. Win10 running longtime installed on an nvme drive. Uefi according to system info in windows and all things setup-menu during boot suggest uefi.
2. This Friday I cleaned out an SSD for ubuntu that's always been in the computer, I found what appeared to be an EFI-partition on that drive confident it had to be the remains of an old installation from another machine or so. It wasn't.
3. After some manual trickery found on neosmart and using easyRE I managed to get my win10 to boot again from a EFI-partition on the nvme.
4. Installed Ubuntu on the other SSD. The "install alongside windows"-path wasn't available when I loaded the USB-drive as UEFI, and when I went there I couldn't get it to show my SSD as a choice, it only showed a mechanical drive I use for project files.
5. I picked "something else" and made one primary ext4 partition for "/" one for swap and one for "/home"
6. End of installation I get the " GRUB couldn't be installed on this partition fatal error ."

Question:

1. How should I proceed now?
2. Where should the efi-files be located, since it's multiple drives? Should both have a partition for them or does the grub-files go into the efi-folders on the nvme(windows)-drive?
3. Can I just copy the files there and from where, or do they need to be "built" for my system?
4. Also, is it important wether I set my root home and swap partitions as primary or logical, and in which order I create them?

Tried so far:

1. Tried boot repair with suggested repair but to no avail. It hinted at success but still boots to win10 and if I force it to windows boot manager it says I need to repair my computer.

Partitions:

[image: Partitions]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171759/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-second-hard-drive-with-windows-being-on-the-first/1165237#1165237)

Comment: Ubuntu's ubiquity installer only installs grub to first ESP partition it sees. You may be able to run Boot-Repair and reinstall grub. But do you have an ESP on first drive? May be best to see details in Boot-Repairs Summary Report first. Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: If by "first" drive you mean the windows drive then yes but it was recreated after the fudgeup of deleting the esp from another drive as I mentioned in the "background" section. I ended up reinstalling windows and things are up and running now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okej so just as an update I ended up backing up important files and scrapping my old windows install for a number of reasons. After a clean install I ended up with an EFS-partition that "looked more genuine".

I suspect in the backstory where I accidentally deleted my EFS and recreated it manually I got it to a state where windows booted again but for some reason it wasn't seen by the ubuntu installer.

It'd been good to work it out and figure out rather than scrapping the install but it was an old install and felt like things just progressed faster.

Another thing I discovered not sure if that's important was that my windows install was MBR and my storage disks and ubuntu install was GPT so I ended up unifying that as well.