# How to dual boot Ubuntu 20 with Win 10 installled on SSD and Ubuntu on HDD?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, ahci, rst

My system configuration is:

```
 1. 256 GB SSD (Win 10 installed)
 2. 2TB HDD (here I want to install Ubuntu with 200 GB space)
 3. UEFI + GPT
 4. Acer Predator Helios 3000
 5. 16GB RAM/ Intel Core i7 9th Gen/ 6GB Nvidia GTX 1660Ti
```

I have pre-installed Win 10 Home on my SSD. I want to install Ubuntu 20 LTS on my HDD with dual boot.

**Here's what I have tried-**

I have read lot of articles and came up with conclusion that the installation of Ubuntu could be proceeded as per the recommendation, with bootloader installed in SSD alongside Windows Boot-Loader in order to get the dual boot done.

**My problem-**

My system uses **SATA Mode-** `RST Premium with Optane` option while booting Windows. If I use this option, then my Ubuntu won't boot. If I set **SATA Mode** from `RST Premium with Optane` to `AHCI`, then Ubuntu gets booted but not Windows.

Here is where I need help. Previously while installing ubuntu, I had also tried to create an EFI partition in HDD, but that also had its own issue (only Ubuntu would boot; for Windows, I have to go again to BIOS and manually select boot option every time, or I have to do some mind-blowing coding in GRUB black screen to boot into Ubuntu some times. A lot of problems).

If its not a big issue, I want to keep the bootloaders of both the OS in SSD. However, I want to install Ubuntu in HDD and keep my Win10 in SSD. Also, after doing the installation, I want a simple dual boot screen from which I could easily boot either of the two OS. No more entering into the BIOS every time I have to toggle my OS.

**Thanks for your answers.**

Comment: All operating systems are supposed to share the same EFI.

Comment: I still like to have an ESP on every drive, even if just for backup. But you have add AHCI drivers into Windows first. Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: @Nmath - I see. I actually read in articles where it was mentioned to create a separate EFI partition while installing Ubuntu. But thanks for your insight.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu on a second hard drive with Windows being on the first?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171759/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-second-hard-drive-with-windows-being-on-the-first)

Answer (score 0):

### Dual Boot Ubuntu 20 with Win 10 on Separate Disks

You do not need to install Ubuntu's bootloader on the same disk as Windows boot loader.

- Assuming Windows boots in UEFI mode:
- Unplug the Windows SSD before installing Ubuntu.
- Boot Ubuntu install USB in UEFI mode.
- Install Ubuntu.
- Plug in Windows SSD.
- Set Ubuntu HDD as first hard drive.
- Boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to Ubuntu's bootloader menu.

This method will preserve the Windows bootloader on the SSD in case the HDD is ever moved or replaced.