# Do All The Warnings of Dual Booting Apply to Me If I am Using a Separate Drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, uefi

On my computer I have a typical SATA SSD (with my current Windows 10 installation) and and another separate M.2 SSD.

I have more than enough space on my normal SSD and would like to install KUbuntu on my M.2 SSD.

As I read through questions about dual booting, I see warnings about things like UEFI, Secure Boot, and Fast Startup and wonder if they apply to me since most of the time it seems as if they are all talking about dual booting from the same drive.

I have the installer flashed to a USB drive right now but I would like to know if I should be worried about anything such as corrupting my Windows installation.

I would like to know if I can keep fast startup on, if I have to change anything with UEFI or secure boot, and if I have to unplug anything like the people on this discussion are talking about;

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd%22)

Also feel free to give me some simple partition layouts geared towards programming for my KUbuntu  installation :)

Comment: If you think you are special, then these warnings don't apply to you. If you are like normal people, then pay attention to the warnings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual Boot on separate drives - best configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-separate-drives-best-configuration)

Comment: @user68186 The reason I ask is because only a select few specify "on a separate drive" when most just say dual booting.

Comment: @d1bro Let me do some reading on what he has to say, it seems promising.

Comment: Most corrupting of Windows/data drives is done by the person installing making a mistake.  Installing on wrong drive/partition is main one.  The other main problem is Windows major updates/upgrades not caring about other OSs, grub gets over written or partition tables messed up.  My opinion only fast start up should be disabled.  It makes life a lot harder if on and Windows dies with no/or partial back up.  It is very hard to retrieve data on dead Windows and fast start up on.

Comment: See [Dual Booting win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate physical ssds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds) and [How can I install Ubuntu on a second hard drive with Windows being on the first?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171759/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-second-hard-drive-with-windows-being-on-the-first)